# How to store the Id of a User securely?

Tags: android, security, userid

When a user logs in from my app, I receive a user-id from the API on a successful login. That ID is then used throughout the app to interact with the API. Currently, I am storing that ID in shared preferences. However, a user with root access can easily change the ID, thus identifying as someone else they are not.

How should I store this id without causing security risk? If this isn't possible what are other alternatives to this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is fundamentally that your app is trusting the user to tell the app who they are via this user ID.  What your app should most likely be returning, and passing back to the app for API use, is a cryptographically based session token that the app knows how to unpack to determine the user's identity, but the user has no way of altering without invalidating it.